# From $\int_{1}^{+\infty} f(x)dx$ is convegent , we can say $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=0$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

From $\int\limits_{1}^{+\infty} f(x)dx$ is convegent , we can say $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=0$?

I think it's true . Because some example for me it. $$\left(\int\limits_{1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{dx}{x^n};\int\limits_{1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{dx}{x^n.e^x};\cdots;\right)n>1$$ But I can't prove it.

Comment: It's not true. Consider a function with bumps of height $1$ at $n \in \mathbb{N}$ which become narrower fast enough to make the integral converge.

Comment: The only thing you can deduce is that $\liminf_{x \to +\infty} |f(x)| =0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, it's not true! The problem is that the convergence of a limit doesn't depend on the height of a function, but the area underneath; if the function is large infinitely often, but with decreasing widths each time, the integral can still converge.

A nice simple example is

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in [n, n + 2^{-n}) \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

where $n$ is restricted to the integers. It's easy to see that the integral is equal to the infinite sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} 2^{-n} $$

which does indeed converge.

Comment: Next: if $\int_{1}^{+\infty} f(x)dx$ is convergent, and $f(x)$ is continuous function in $(1,\infty)$, then can we say $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=0$?

Comment: @kaka: Make triangles instead of rectangles. If you want $f$ to be smooth, then make bump functions instead of triangles.